# Why am I banned from posting islamic question?

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange

Why is this asking question through other stackexchange sites has banned me from asking questions related to islam? How to get out of this?

Answer (score 2):

You triggered the low-quality question ban because a large number of your questions were deemed low-quality. I can't give the exact reason for this since every question would need to be judged separately, but in general this happens when a questioner doesn't understand the purpose of our site.

**We are a site for learning about the topic of Islam. We are not, however, an Islamic site.**

We have quality control standards for a reason. Unlike the Islamic Q&A sites run by trained scholars, we are not capable of giving legal verdicts or providing personalized advice. We expect all users to be able to do their own research, and it is vital that they have the critical skills to understand the information we provide rather than just blindly taking it as fact. The quality of your questions reflects that.

If users expect answers here to be authoritative, as one would get from an Islamic site, there is a very real risk of misinformation and falsehood being spread. Not only is this a very real concern for the quality of the site, but it can be dangerous to any future users who lack the basic skills to discern a good answer from a wrong one.

**There are many Islamic questions, or questions related to Islam, that are not a good fit here.** For the purposes of this site, we need questions that understand that "Islam" refers to every possible interpretation of Islam, and focus accordingly. For the purposes of this site, we need questions that focus on facts, not opinions. For the purposes of this site, we need questions that make actual information easier to find for future users, not to further muddy the waters.